# What is the migration procedure for moving from Windows system-wide Visual Studio Code to user setup?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am an existing user of the system-wide distribution of Visual Studio Code. I have been prompted to switch to the new User Setup distribution. This directs me to download the user setup installer. When running this installer, it tells me that I should uninstall the existing installation before installing the new one.

The uninstall procedure doesn't give any indication that settings and extensions will be kept.

I want to ensure that I keep all of my existing settings and extensions when moving to the new version. Is this possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have tried the new distribution and confirmed that extensions will be kept.

Please note that the default install location of this distribution is `<OS drive>:\Users\<Your username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code`

The two distributions share the same .vscode folder and setting. It doesn't force you to remove the system wide distribution when install the user distribution. If you have 2 distributions at the same time, when you open the system wide distribution it will remind you yo use the user distribution instead.

Comment: Hi this means that removing the previous system wide install and installing the user setup doesn't brake anything?. I'm not sold into it yet.

Comment: They share the same .vscode folder (which store your extensions), extensions' setting, have difference install location and it doesn't ask you to remove the system wide distribution. But I don't remember if you uninstall the system wide distribution first, the .vscode folder is deleted or not, so if you don't want to have 2 distribution at a same time, install this first then uninstall the system wide distribution just in case.

Comment: I uninstalled first, then installed user setup version and every extension was still there as well as my color themes and settings.

Comment: Indeed, you remove the system wide and then install the user setup and everything is just like it was before. Thanks guys!!!

Comment: @IngóVals, thanks for the heads up. So it's true, VSCode just leaves garbage behind during an uninstall.

Comment: I uninstall vscode (to try to solve a problem), it says something like "are you sure you want to delete everything". I said yes. I then reinstalled it, it just came as if nothing happened (it even keept my tabs opened). (great, but VScode should tell that it will keep the settings config).

Answer (score 3):

I have also got the following message in Visual Studio Code:

> You are running the system-wide installation of Code, while having the user-wide distribution installed as well. Make sure you're running the Code version you expect.

I get this if I open Visual Studio Code from:

> $Drive:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe

If I open code from the users applications, I don't get that issue:

> $Drive:\Users\$userName\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe

I have both versions installed, I first had the system-wide distribution, then installed the user-wide distribution, without removing the system-wide distribution. After the install the extensions and settings from my existing system-wide distribution are available in the user-wide distribution without any issues.

This was a new feature released in VSC 2018 July, v1.26: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_26#_user-setup-for-windows

I originally had the system-wide installation only, then I installed the user-wide distribution. Occasionally, I would accidentally open the system-wide distribution. I have now uninstalled the system-wide installation, and the user-wide installation is working fine.

You can differentiate between the 2 installations in the "Add Remove Programs" feature by the presence of the "User" label. [image: Add Remove Programs]

No problems with extensions, all are still working after removing the system-wide install.

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed the new version VS Code and without uninstall previous version, you will get the message when you open VS Code by command line.

To resolve the issue, you should remove the system environment variable about previous version path, maybe `<OS drive>:\ProgramFiles\Microsoft VS Code\bin`.

Rapid Environment Editor is recommend to use. This tool has two split window, left one is system variable, right one is user variable. Remove path of VS Code in left window and save. Restart the system and open VS Code again by command line.

Removing the previous system wide install and installing the user setup doesn't brake anything. If everything is good, you can remove it.

Hope to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to avoid the warning (if you have both installed, like I do - I too was worried about settings), is to search for visual studio code through windows (10) search. Only the ' user-wide distribution' gets found that way. If you open visual studio code that way, the warning is gone.

I too can confirm settings and plugins will remain installed.