# Will the settings & extensions would be retained after switching to new Windows setup?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I did the update and got recommendation I now use new Windows Setup. I clicked learn more and went to site page that said I would be prompted to switch and all my settings & extensions would be retained, but there was no prompt to switch. The prompt was to download. I did, and when went to install, got message saying I should uninstall prior installation. It is not at all clear that my settings and extensions will in fact be kept. Does anyone know for sure. I don't want to uninstall, install new version, and then discover that all my settings and extensions have been wiped out. Please help?

Comment: He tagged the question wrong, corrected.

Comment: I uninstalled and then installed the July "user install" update a few days ago.  As far as I can tell, all my settings and extensions were preserved.

Comment: Thanks for correcting the tag.

Comment: Ok, I'm about to try then. Thought just in case, I'll do a backup I can go back to, if it fails. Thanks Bacon Bits.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the migration procedure for moving from Windows system-wide Visual Studio Code to user setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51831578/what-is-the-migration-procedure-for-moving-from-windows-system-wide-visual-studi)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I should have followed up on this a long time ago. My question wasn't at all clear. It was about updating to a new version of Visual Studio Code. I had been instructed to uninstall the prior installation first. I feared that uninstalling would wipe out all my prior settings and configuration changes.

I later found from VSCode that uninstalling would not do so, but that they would be retained in the new installation. They were.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if the settings and extension are preserved when you are making the switch.

But I can recommend few ways in which you can preserve your settings and extensions.

1. [Sync settings](https://github.com/shanalikhan/code-settings-sync)
2. Create a symbolic link between both of your editors in which you can share the same setting and extension, without worrying about keeping the setting and extension in sync with both the editors.